# Stretch a Div to Browser width when inside many containers

Tags: html, css

I have read answers on Stackoverflow, on how to stretch a div to full width when inside a fixed width container. But those are valid only if the content is inside one fixed container, what if the content is inside many `div` tags whose widths have been differently specified.

```
<div class='container' width="50%">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div class="container-to-stretch"> Some Content </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Setting `position` to `absolute` and `left` and `right` to `0` simply doesn't work.

Comment: @twntee What if a parent div has `position: relative`?

Comment: @twntee, same question which putvande asked!

Comment: simple, then it fails. over enthusiasm kills sometimes, although setting `position:fixed` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

here is a jsfiddle that will help you http://jsfiddle.net/Fm7M5/

in your example (if i understand the question correctly), once CONTAINER has a width of 50%, that width is 100% for all of it's nested elements. so, the unclassed divs & CONTAINER-TO-STRETCH all have an automatic width that is 100% of CONTAINER.

so, you will need give CONTAINER-TO-STRETCH a width that larger than the width of its container.

in the jsfiddle, you can see the following (where TEST is a class given to one of the unclassed divs)

```
    .container {
    background-color: red;
}

.container-to-stretch {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 400%;
}

.test {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

so, CONTAINER has a width that is 50% of the body, TEST has a width that is 25% of 50% of the body, and CONTAINER-TO-STRETCH has a width that is 400% of 25% of 50% of the body.

Comment: hmm, your question is 'how to make an inner div stretch to the width of it's grandparent div when all divs have a fixed width'?